# Activation of network connection failed

Tags: networking, wireless

Good afternoon,

I cannot get my wifi card to connect to a network. I can see a list of wifi networks, however, it fails to connect with the error periodically shown "Connection failed, Activation of network connection failed".

System: Ubuntu 21.04 with Windows 10 Dual Boot - No fast boot enabled in windows.

Wifi card: asus pce-ac88

The wifi works okay, albeit REALLY slow and patchy, with a cheap USB WIFI stick.

Answer (score 0):

{Im using windows 10 along side Ubuntu 21.10}

so i found the problem with mine, so i used command `ifconfig` in nmy terminal and showed this:

```
enp5s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether bc: 0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
 RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 45  base 0x9000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 0.0.0.0  netmask 0.0.0.0
        inet6 ::0 prefixlen 0  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 420  bytes 45563 (45.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 420  bytes 45563 (45.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp11s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::0 prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0 txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24237  bytes 34577754 (34.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14708  bytes 1517105 (1.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

by plugging this command you want to see if is there any other adapters in your computer to select, as you can see device "`enp5s0`" is being interrupted for many times and gives the code "Activation of Network Connection Failed" about 5 to 10 min so i want to disable, what i did was disable this guy by using command `sudo ifconfig enp5s0 down` since is selected up and i don't want to use it anymore  and left the `wlp11s0:Up` so i want to use this adapter, for some reason i have to do this every time i restart PC or retart the NetworkManager, make sure you know your adapter name but in any case you want to change just replace the Down for Up or restart the network manager in the command, Hope this Helps, and yes i'm  using the old fashion way of ifconfig this still works in UBUNTU 21.10