# Activation of network connection failed after connection drops

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, realtek

Similar to this question: [Activation of network connection failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342065/activation-of-network-connection-failed), but I have the following issue. The machine boots and connects to wifi on bootup, but if the connection drops (for any reason), then the connection does not restart and gives the error message "Activation of network connection failed". I have to reboot the machine for it to reconnect. This also happens if I try to connect to a different network after that first connection.

Nothing I have tried fixes the issue, either manually attempting to connect to the wifi network, nor stopping/restarting network manager via systemctl.

Is there anything else I can try to fix this so I do not need to reboot each time it drops?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, with kernel version 5.8.0-63-generic, as I have a Realtek RTL8723DE wifi adapter, and there is no updated driver (from here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88) available for later kernel versions (see my previous question here: [Realtek wifi driver for RTL8723DE for linux kernel version 5.11.0-26-generic (ubuntu 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356162/realtek-wifi-driver-for-rtl8723de-for-linux-kernel-version-5-11-0-26-generic-ub))

Note that I do not have access to the router for a wired connection, so wifi is my only option for connecting.

EDIT: following the comment below, I've added the output of `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` to https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WgTt6KGyyj/, showing the network connecting first time, then failing to connect after I've toggled the wifi off and back on again, the moving through a cycle like:

```
Jun 14 21:07:40 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237260.5736] sup-iface[0x56336ea5ba10,wlo1]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Jun 14 21:07:40 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237260.5778] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jun 14 21:07:40 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237260.5780] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:07:40 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237260.5828] device (wlo1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.3582] policy: auto-activating connection 'Top Flat' (6a3647ab-a928-4d36-b895-e6a53f857391)
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.3595] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'Top Flat' (6a3647ab-a928-4d36-b895-e6a53f857391)
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.3599] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.3610] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.6724] device (wlo1): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to A4:FC:77:7C:A3:0D (preserve)
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.6727] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.6731] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Top Flat' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.6731] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7303] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7303] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: ready -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7304] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7305] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7327] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7334] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7339] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Top Flat' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7340] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Top Flat'
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7340] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7341] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7341] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7341] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7644] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:42 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237262.7645] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:44 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237264.4815] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:44 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237264.4823] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:44 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237264.5860] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:44 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237264.5862] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:45 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237265.9966] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:45 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237265.9966] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:46 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237266.0819] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:46 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237266.0821] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:47 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237267.4902] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:47 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237267.4910] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:47 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237267.9780] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:47 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237267.9782] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:49 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237269.3960] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:49 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237269.3961] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:49 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237269.8740] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:49 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237269.8742] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:51 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237271.2798] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:51 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237271.2798] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:52 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237272.2704] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:52 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237272.2705] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:53 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237273.6836] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:53 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237273.6843] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:54 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237274.6710] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:54 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237274.6712] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:07:56 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237276.0713] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:07:56 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237276.0713] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:08:01 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237281.3994] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:08:01 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237281.3995] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 14 21:08:06 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237286.1046] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:08:06 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237286.1046] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 14 21:08:07 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <warn>  [1655237287.6290] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jun 14 21:08:07 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237287.6291] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:08:07 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237287.6302] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 14 21:08:07 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <warn>  [1655237287.6390] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'Top Flat'
Jun 14 21:08:07 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237287.6494] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:08:07 HP-Laptop-15-db0598sa NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1655237287.6666] device (wlo1): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 4A:D0:E7:0C:83:44 (scanning)
```

EDIT2: I also disabled random MAC switching in NetworkManager, which didn't solve the issue either

EDIT3: I have taken snapshots of the wifi config using the script for this question: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) when the wifi is up and when it is not (and fails to reconnect)

Working/connected: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dTFptYhv8N/

Not working/not connecting: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/PPhHZNWcfd/

EDIT4: I've booted and rebooted into 5.13.0-48 and it seems to be more stable, so watch this space!

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. I've written a bash script to help with this type of problem: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.

Comment: Thanks, but if I don't know what I need to reconnect (and the connection is dropping more often now than before), then how would I use it to get back connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the edit (4) above: I've booted now into 5.13.0-48, which wasn't seeing the adapter before, but now appears to be, and the connection comes back up after I turn it off/on again, so it might not have the "activation of network connection failed" issue in the question.

If it happens with this latest kernel version, I'll open a brand new Q when it does.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been trying to post this in all the threads I was looking at, but here is a bandaid that might help.  The original solver gets the credit.  [Wifi keeps dropping out - Ubuntu 20.04 and Broadcom wireless adaptor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230140/wifi-keeps-dropping-out-ubuntu-20-04-and-broadcom-wireless-adaptor/1414054#1414054)